# How to Send ajax post with image src to zend controller and save it in the database without using send form

Tags: ajax, view, model, controller, zend-framework2

i would like to know how to get data from ajax call from view to zend controller and save it using zend table function. so now below is my code.

this is my controller

```
    public function addAction(){    

    $image_uri =  $this->getRequest()->getPost('image_uri');
    $personalmug = new PersonalMug();
    $personalmug->exchangeArray($image_uri);
    $this->getPersonalMugTable()->save($personalmug);



}
```

this is my ajax code.

```
    $('#buttonSave').click(function (){
        var image_uri = $("mug1").attr("src");
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'http://toxicfox.com/personal-mug/add',
                async: false,

                // you can use an object here
                data: { image_uri: image_uri},
                success: function(json) {
                    console.log(json.image_uri);
                }
            });
        // you might need to do this, to prevent anchors from following
        // or form controls from submitting

    });
```

this is my save function from zend table class.

```
    public function save(PersonalMug $personalmug){
    $data = array(
        'image_uri'  => $personalmug->image_uri,
    );

    $image_id = (int) $$personalmug->image_id;
    if($image_id == 0){
        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
    }else{
        if($this->getImage($image_id)){
            $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('image_id' => $image_id));
        }else{
            throw new \Exception('Mug id does not exist');
        }
    }
}
```

this is my model class

```
class PersonalMug{
public $image_id;

public $image_uri;

public function exchangeArray($data){
    $this->image_id = (!empty($data['image_id'])) ? $data['image_id'] : null;
    $this->image_uri  = (!empty($data['image_uri'])) ? $data['image_uri'] : null;
}
```

}

Comment: everything looks fine except for this:   $image_id = (int) $$personalmug->image_id; it should be:   $image_id = (int) $personalmug->image_id;

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: there is problem of getting the image src in jquery function it is always send null post and you were correct i have to remove the double dollar sign but now i am getting this error Statement could not be executed (23000 - 1048 - Le champ 'image_uri' ne peut être vide (null))

Comment: and this error also SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'image_uri' ne peut être vide (null), do i have to send the id of image also but the id is auto generated

Comment: after putting it back i mean the dollar sign i am having this error Catchable fatal error: Object of class PersonalMug\Model\PersonalMug could not be converted to string

Comment: your other problem is on:       var image_uri = $("mug1").attr("src"); mug1 is not a tag, is it an id?a class? please post the html from where you want to get the src attribute

Comment: the problem is solved , i forgot to put # symboll with mug1 in jquery, and the dollar sign was a problem, and in the controller i have to put the image_uri as array, i will upload my solution.

Comment: hi , i would like to know after saving how can i display message or alert, please help

Comment: replace this:  console.log(json.image_uri); with this alert(json.image_uri);

Comment: hi i cannot redirect after saving the data could you please help me in redirecting thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, i had some small mistakes and i was inserting the string instead of obeject. i hope it will help someone else also . below is the controller code with small mistakes corrected, it works fine now .
Mistakes.

1. I have used refrenced variable in the personalmugtable,

   $image_id = (int) $$personalmug->image_id;
2. i have not used # sybmol in the jquery,

   var image_uri = $("mug1").attr("src");
3. I was insert string instead of object in the controller.

   public function addAction(){

   $data['image_uri'] =  $this->getRequest()->getPost('image_uri');
   $personalmug = new PersonalMug();
   $personalmug->exchangeArray($data);
   $this->getPersonalMugTable()->save($personalmug);
   return $this->redirect()->toRoute('personal-mug');

   }